# How to write a regex which match a sentence if a set of multi-word sentences are not present

Tags: regex

As per the title **How to write a regex which match a sentence if a set of multi-word sentences are not present** ?

Example:

- Sentence: This is a sentence with several words any more than eight whatever
- match sentence only if it doesn't contain "several words" and "eight whatever" (in this case the sentence would not be matched since "several words" appear)

I am aware of the `negative lookahead operator` but I could not find an example which satisfy the conditions

- they shall be **sentences** (i.e. more than 1 word)
- any matching sentence in the "blacklist" shall trigger a **non match**

The implementation language shall be irrelevant, as  I plan to use this in an IFTTT applet to filter a RSS feed (Inoreader)

Comment: how do you define a sentence where it begins and ends?

Comment: `match = /sentence/ && ! /phrase1|phrase2|.../`

Comment: So you have two goals: 1) Find a sentence (starts somewhere and ends somewhere specific) 2) Ignore it if it matches some patterns. Right? Now for the first requirement please define the **sentence**.

Comment: in case a sentence ends with a dot, [this regex](https://regex101.com/r/REvztr/1/) may help